# Using LINQ JOIN on Dictionary with Custom Datatype and DataGridView rows

Tags: c#, .net, linq, join

```cs
//Use LINQ to join the selected games with dSourceGames on Matching IDs

List<Game> games = 
    from row in dgv.Rows
    join game in dSourceGames on dSourceGames.Values.Select(x=>x.ID).Contains(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString()) equals true
    select game;
    //select new {new Game(game.Title,game.ID,game.Region,game.Extension,game.Size,game.Path) };
```

**So, I have a Dictionary<int,Game> and a DataGridView displaying information about the same games. Game is a Custom Datatype. Duh..**

I'm looking to instead of looping through each row, finding out if it is selected, getting the IDs, adding them to a list. Comparing that list against a Dictionary of Custom Datatypes, and run a foreach on the resulting list.

The Game Datatype has more information what is shown in the DataGridView, and there are no FULL FULL constructors.

I've been working with C# for a long time, but have been out of it for a while. Learning a lot more has changed with new language updates, and frameworks. Not to mention just being a touch out of practice.

Any help or suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Can you show the code that you want to change or improve?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to use `from` clause instead of `join` clause.

```cs
from row in dgv.Rows
from game in dSourceGames.Values
where game.Id == row.Cells[2].Value.ToString()
select game;
```

This uses an inner join to accept `game`s that have an `Id` which is one of the `Value` of `row.Cells[2]`s and reject all others. Or you can say, this accept `row.Cells[2].Value`s included in `game.Id`s together with other corresponding properties of the `game`.